# Multiple web Application in on site

Tags: asp.net, shared-hosting, plesk

1 - I Want To Deploy Two Website in One Host and Maybe different ASP Version , so how can I do it , and fully isolate from each other ?

---

2 - in plesk how can add new Addone domain , i cant see thisoption in plesk!

Comment: only if you split them in different root directories - even then you may have issues.

Comment: how about using application pool , it helps me to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plesk has "webspace" or "subscription" concept for isolation. May be it is what you call "Host". In order to keep sites fully isolated and running different .Net version you will need to put sites in different webspaces (if you are server owner). If you are on shared hosting, you will need to ask your provider for another subscription.

You can add multiple sites (addon domains) in one webspace/subscription. Just click "Add new domain" in "Websites and Domains" tab. These sites can be put in different folders (docroot), but aren't fully isolated, i.e. they could share some common library and files.